# Atomic operations on memory mapped files

Tags: multithreading, go, thread-safety, atomic

I'm using a memory mapped file and I need to use an atomic store on Go. I would use StoreUint64() if I were working on regularly allocated memory. However, I'm not sure how atomic operations work on memory mapped files.

Is it safe to use StoreUint64() on memory mapped files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's safe. For example, on `amd64`, it uses the `XCHG` instruction.

> [`func StoreUint64`](http://golang.org/pkg/sync/atomic/#StoreUint64)
>
> ```
>     func StoreUint64(addr *uint64, val uint64)
> ```
>
> `StoreUint64` atomically stores `val` into `*addr`.

[`src/sync/atomic/asm_amd64.s`](http://golang.org/src/sync/atomic/asm_amd64.s);

```
TEXT ·StoreUint64(SB),NOSPLIT,$0-16
    MOVQ    addr+0(FP), BP
    MOVQ    val+8(FP), AX
    XCHGQ   AX, 0(BP)
    RET
```

> **Intel 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer's Manual**
>
> `XCHG`—Exchange Register/Memory with Register
>
> Description
>
> Exchanges the contents of the destination (first) and
>   source (second) operands. The operands can be two general-purpose
>   registers or a register and a memory location. If a memory operand is
>   referenced, the processor’s locking protocol is automatically
>   implemented for the duration of the exchange operation, regardless of
>   the presence or absence of the LOCK prefix or of the value of the
>   IOPL.